# phpunit custom asserts help needed

Tags: php, phpunit, assert

I'm trying to add a custom assert to phpunit, following [this tutorial](http://raphaelstolt.blogspot.com/2008/07/creating-custom-phpunit-assertions.html), to validate complex numbers returned as a string (e.g.

> "-123+456i"

by the method that I'm testing) to a defined precision for both the real and imaginary components. I've put a Complex.php class to parse the string into the real and imaginary parts, and put together the following assertion class as complexAssert.php:

```
require_once 'PHPUnit/Framework/Assert.php';
include_once getcwd().'/custom/Complex.php';

class complexAssert extends PHPUnit_Framework_Assert {

    public function assertComplexEquals($expected, $actual, $message = '', $delta = 0)
    {
        $expectedComplex = new Complex($expected);
        $actualComplex = new Complex($actual);

        if (!($actualComplex->getReal() >= ($expectedComplex - $delta) &&
            $actualComplex->getReal() <= ($expectedComplex + $delta))) {
            return $this->fail($message);
        }

        if (!($actualComplex->getImaginary() >= ($expectedComplex - $delta) &&
            $actualComplex->getImaginary() <= ($expectedComplex + $delta))) {
            return $this->fail($message);
        }

    }
}
```

My unit test script:

```
require_once getcwd().'/custom/complexAssert.php';
require_once 'testDataFileIterator.php';

class EngineeringTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * @dataProvider providerIMSUM
     */
    public function testIMSUM()
    {
        $args = func_get_args();
        $expectedResult = array_pop($args);
        $result = call_user_func_array(array('PHPExcel_Calculation_Engineering','IMSUM'),$args);
        $this->assertComplexEquals($expectedResult, $result);
    }

    public function providerIMSUM()
    {
        return new testDataFileIterator('rawTestData/Calculation/Engineering/IMSUM.data');
    }
}
```

The unit tests worked without error (but failed) when I was simply doing an assertEquals... but now I've added the include and changed to my new assert, it's crashing claiming that it can't call the undefined method assertComplexEquals().

Has anybody had any success extending phpunit with custom asserts, and can see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You could better follow official http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/extending-phpunit.html#extending-phpunit.custom-assertions

Comment: While unrelated to this problem, you might want to use `__DIR__` (PHP 5.3+) or `dirname(__FILE__)` rather than depending on the current working directory which can change while the program runs.

Comment: @David Harkness: I bet that in his case `getcwd() != __DIR__`

Comment: @zerkms - That's quite possible, but the danger of using `getcwd()` is that it can change depending on the environment (testing vs. production), yet inclusion of other modules often needs to work no matter what environment is active. Better to either depend on the current script's location or the include path with autoloading.

Comment: @David Harkness: yep, but currently OP also relies on relative locations of his new assertion (which is library thing) and his complex number implementation (which in fact is an application part thing). And this is also not a good thing either

Comment: I've switched to using __DIR__ rather than getcwd(), but this isn't the cause of my problem... the Complex and complexAssert classes were being successfully included, but the assertComplexEquals() method isn't available within the context of the PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase class... I still only have access to the standard "built-in" assert methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I chose not to extend existing asserts, but to modify my complex assertion logic to return a simple boolean, that could then be tested using assertTrue(), and with an error message that could be retrieved with a simple getMessage() for display in the phpunit results. To be honest, it feels a whole lot easier to use this way

```
include_once __DIR__.'/Complex.php';

class complexAssert {

    private $_errorMessage = '';

    public function assertComplexEquals($expected, $actual, $delta = 0)
    {
        $expectedComplex = new Complex($expected);
        $actualComplex = new Complex($actual);

        if ($actualComplex->getReal() < ($expectedComplex->getReal() - $delta) ||
            $actualComplex->getReal() > ($expectedComplex->getReal() + $delta)) {
            $this->_errorMessage = 'Mismatched Real part: ' .
                                   $actualComplex->getReal() . 
                                   ' !== ' . 
                                   $expectedComplex->getReal();
            return FALSE;
        }

        if ($actualComplex->getImaginary() < ($expectedComplex->getImaginary() - $delta) ||
            $actualComplex->getImaginary() > ($expectedComplex->getImaginary() + $delta)) {
            $this->_errorMessage = 'Mismatched Imaginary part: ' .
                                   $actualComplex->getImaginary() . 
                                   ' !== ' . 
                                   $expectedComplex->getImaginary();
            return FALSE;
        }

        return TRUE;
    }

    public function getErrorMessage() {
        return $this->_errorMessage;
    }
}
```

My unit test script:

```
//  Custom assertion class for handling precision of Complex numbers
require_once __DIR__.'/../../custom/complexAssert.php';
//  Data Provider handler
require_once 'testDataFileIterator.php';

class EngineeringTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * @dataProvider providerIMSUM
     */
    public function testIMSUM()
    {
        $args = func_get_args();
        $expectedResult = array_pop($args);
        $result = call_user_func_array(array('PHPExcel_Calculation_Engineering','IMSUM'),$args);
        $complexAssert = new complexAssert();
        $this->assertTrue($complexAssert->assertComplexEquals($expectedResult, $result, 1E-8),
                          $complexAssert->getErrorMessage());
    }

    public function providerIMSUM()
    {
        return new testDataFileIterator('rawTestData/Calculation/Engineering/IMSUM.data');
    }
}
```

and the logged phpunit result is clear enough:

```
3) EngineeringTest::testIMSUB with data set #7 ('-12.34-5.67i', '-123.45-67.89', '#NUM!')
Mismatched String: 111.11 !== #NUM!
Failed asserting that false is true.
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the only way to get `$this->someCustomAssertion` worked is to extend `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` and create wrapper-methods there, or call your custom assertions statically.

Zend Framework, for example, just extends `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` with additional methods (assertions)